# Creating a custom MessageBox class for MFC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, dialog

I'm trying to create a Modeless Messagebox class in MFC 6.0. The end result should look pretty similar to this:

[image]

I'm trying to add an icon with the following, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
    HICON hIcon = LoadIcon(AfxGetInstanceHandle(), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ERROR));
    SetIcon(hIcon, FALSE);
```

Also, is there a way to set the background color of the top part of a dialog to a different color from the rest of the dialog?

Comment: You don't need to create a custom message box. All of the features shown/demanded, can be achieved configuring the standard `MessageBox` dialog appropriately already.

Comment: MessageBoxes are modal. I need a Modeless one.

Comment: You just need to create a dialog, and put controls into it to match the appearance and behavior of a MessageBox. A lot more work than it ought to be, but not horrible either.

Comment: P.S. If you have a choice, you should upgrade to the newest version of Visual Studio, the Community edition is free and includes MFC.  VC6 is painfully ancient.

Comment: The Community edition is free under certain conditions.  It isn't free to everybody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some design issues here, for this type of interface the program should save automatically. If user is deleting the file then confirm it with modeless dialog. This way data is not lost if user is impatient. Anyway, you can just override OnPaint etc. and draw the icon

```
void CMyDlg::OnPaint()
{
    CDialog::OnPaint();
    //draw white rectangle on top-half of dialog 
    //draw lt-gray rectangle at bottom-half, GetSysColor(COLOR_BTNFACE)
    HICON hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_ERROR);
    dc.DrawIcon(x, y, hIcon);
    DestroyIcon(hIcon);
}

BOOL CMyDlg::OnEraseBkgnd(CDC* pDC)
{
    return 1;
}
```

You might also need to override OnCtlColor